# ActionBarSherlock spinner item background ignored

Tags: android, styles, spinner, actionbarsherlock

I have a share action item, and no matter what I do the spinner does not seem to respect the styles I set. I used the style generator here http://jgilfelt.github.com/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

Here is a snippet of my themes file

```
<style name="Theme.Next" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_next</item>
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/next_PopupMenu</item>
    <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/next_DropDownListView</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/next_ActionBarTabStyle</item>
    <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/next_DropDownNav</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/next_solid_ActionBar</item>

    <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_next</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/next_PopupMenu</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/next_DropDownListView</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/next_ActionBarTabStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/next_DropDownNav</item>

    <!-- Light.DarkActionBar specific -->
    <item name="actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/Theme.next.widget</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/Theme.next.widget</item>

</style>

<style name="next_DropDownNav" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar">
        <item name="background">@drawable/spinner_background_ab_next</item>

        <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background_ab_next</item>
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_next</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_next</item>
    </style>

<!-- this style is only referenced in a Light.DarkActionBar based theme -->
    <style name="Theme.next.widget" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
        <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/next_PopupMenu</item>
        <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/next_DropDownListView</item>

        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/next_PopupMenu</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/next_DropDownListView</item>
    </style>
```

spinner_background_ab_next points to a selector with my proper custom drawables. No matter what I change, the share spinner always uses the default ICS blue. Anyone run into this problem?